# Como sumar elementos de un Objecto en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, javascript-objeto

recibo el siguiente **JSON**. y necesito sumar el **object** dentro del array llamado : POWETSTATS. q

```
 "results": [
        {
            "id": "35",
            "name": "Apocalypse",
            "powerstats": {
                "intelligence": "100",
                "strength": "100",
                "speed": "33",
                "durability": "100",
                "power": "100",
                "combat": "60"
            },
            "biography": {
                "full-name": "En Sabah Nur",
                "alter-egos": "No alter egos found.",
                "aliases": [
                    "The Eternal One",
                    "the High Lord",
                    "Set",
                    "Huitxilopochti",
                    "Sauru",
                    "Kali-Ma"
                ],
                "place-of-birth": "Akkaba, Egypt",
                "first-appearance": "X-Factor #5 (June, 1986)",
                "publisher": "Marvel Comics",
                "alignment": "bad"
            },
            "appearance": {
                "gender": "Male",
                "race": "Mutant",
                "height": [
                    "7'0",
                    "213 cm"
                ],
                "weight": [
                    "300 lb",
                    "135 kg"
                ],
                "eye-color": "Red",
                "hair-color": "Black"
            }
]
```

El JSON que recibo, tiene muchos elementos mas.
Es decir, tengo que recorrer ese array, entrar en el campo POWERSTATS y ese campo que es un Object tengo que sumar todos los campos de ese Object, es decir..
`**"intelligence" : "100" + "strength":"100"**` -> sumar esos values. y la respuesta que quiero seria 200(en este ejemplo chico, quiero el total de todo ese Object).
Estuve intetando con MAP + REDUCE y no logro el objetivo. Vale aclarar que estoy programando en React JS.
**Gracias comunidad!!!**

Comment: Debes acceder al elemento, por ejemplo `objeto.results[0].powerstats` y puedes obtener los valores como arreglo con [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) para recorrer con `map()` y sumarlos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo que sugiere @Triby en el comentario. Obtener los valores con el metodo `Object.values()` del objeto `powerstats`, pero en este caso usar el metodo `.reduce()` para sumar dichos valores.

```javascript
const total = Object.values(results[0].powerstats).reduce((prev, curr) => prev + Number(curr), 0)
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, me sirvio de mucho!